# Question is marked as duplicate without link to original

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60779571/9254539) which is marked as a duplicate, but the duplicate banner doesn't appear to contain a link to the original question. Is this a bug?

[image: duplicate banner without link to original question]

Comment: This issue happens on multiple sites, thus should be posted on MSE, and luckily there is already a report of the issue: [Closed as a duplicate, but the duplicate list is empty?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/345289)

Comment: I've reopened and closed using the link of the comment. I hope it's okay.